# Centralize data in Service Layer

Tags: c#

Please see this code

```
public class MedierService : Singleton<MedierService>
{
    PresseEntities _db = new PresseEntities();
    IQueryable<Medier> _mediers;

    public MedierService()
    {
        _mediers = _db.Mediers.Select(s => s);
    }

    public List<Medier> GetAll(MedierStatus m)
    {
        var retVal = Enumerable.Empty<Medier>();
        switch (m)
        {
            case MedierStatus.New:
                retVal = _mediers.Where(w => w.vis == 1 && w.dato_slettet == new DateTime(1900, 01, 01));
                break;
            case MedierStatus.Deleted:
                retVal = _mediers.Where(w => w.vis == 1 && w.dato_slettet != new DateTime(1900, 01, 01));
                break;
        }
        return retVal.ToList();
    }
}
```

**vs**

```
public class MedierService : Singleton<MedierService>
{
    PresseEntities _db = new PresseEntities();

    IQueryable<Medier> _GetAll()
    {
        return _db.Mediers.Select(s => s);
    }

    public List<Medier> GetAll(MedierStatus m)
    {
        var retVal = Enumerable.Empty<Medier>();
        switch (m)
        {
            case MedierStatus.New:
                retVal = _GetAll().Where(w => w.vis == 1 && w.dato_slettet == new DateTime(1900, 01, 01));
                break;
            case MedierStatus.Deleted:
                retVal = _GetAll().Where(w => w.vis == 1 && w.dato_slettet != new DateTime(1900, 01, 01));
                break;
        }
        return retVal.ToList();
    }
}
```

Alright, so above codes will both return me the same exact result after calling `MedierService.Instance.GetAll(MedierStatus.New)`.

I am completely new to C# and I hope my code makes sense.

What I am trying to do here is to make a centralize `_mediers` and `_GetAll`  so I can easily filter the results if the filter is global, so I don't have to go line by line and put the filter.

**Now my problem is**

I dont know if I am doing it right, in my first example, I made it by using constructor and created a variable `_mediers`, but on the second one I just created a private method named `_GetAll()`.

So here are my questions:
1.) What is the right way of doing it? The first one or the next one?

2.) Is it ok to make `_mediers` and `_GetAll()` IQueryable so it won't load all of the data from my database and let my methods filter it?

3.) Is it ok to prefix underscore to my method `_GetAll()` because it is a private method?

4.) Is there anyway you can enhance my code?

All your answers will greatly help me and enhance my coding skills.
Thank so much

Comment: Your GetAll() method can just say `return _db.Mediers` - no select needed. Also, the underscore naming convention should be used for private fields, but not methods. Private methods should be declared `private` and begin with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per question. Also, currently your question is almost entirely opinion-based. If you have working code, that is your own code, and you want to know what you can do to improve it, [codereview.se] might be a better site. Please do read their help center to ensure your question is on topic.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a single GetAll method (i.e. remove the _GetAll method and no  constructor required)

```
public List<Medier> GetAll(MedierStatus m)
{
  var date = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01);
  var retVal = _db.Mediers
        .Where(w => w.vis == 1 && 
               ((w.dato_slettet == date && m == MedierStatus.New)
             || (w.dato_slettet != date && m == MedierStatus.Deleted)));


  return retVal.ToList();
}
```

As for the prefix to indicate a private method, rather explicity use the private access modifier.

```
private IQueryable<Medier> GetAll() {...}
```